# Variable not being set with return value

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, typeerror

```
class Person
  constructor: (@name, @org, @phone, @email) ->
    alert "#{name}: #{org} #{phone} #{email}"

__create = (title) ->
  p =
    name: ""
    org: "_organization"
    phone: "_phone"
    email: "_email"

  (p[pr] = "%#{title}#{p[pr]}%" for pr of p)

  Person(p.name, p.org, p.phone, p.email)

m = __create "author"

alert m.name
```

This consistently gives me:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

However, the compiled JavaScript clearly assigns `m` a value:

```js
__create = function(title) {
  var p, pr;
  p = {
    name: "",
    org: "_organization",
    phone: "_phone",
    email: "_email"
  };
  for (pr in p) {
    p[pr] = "%" + title + p[pr] + "%";
  }
  return Person(p.name, p.org, p.phone, p.email);
};

m = __create("author");

alert(m.name);
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `new` operator, e.g.,

```
__create = (title) ->
  p =
    name: ""
    org: "_organization"
    phone: "_phone"
    email: "_email"

  (p[pr] = "%#{title}#{p[pr]}%" for pr of p)

  new Person(p.name, p.org, p.phone, p.email)
```

http://coffeescript.org/#classes

Comment: How about that --- no, I didn't know that you needed to, but that's a fix.  (I have only a cursory understanding of specific javascript syntax...)  I'll accept when I can, and thanks for the link :) Don't know how that tidbit slipped past me.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is it returning when I omit the `new`?

Comment: @SeanAllred The return value of `alert`, which doesn't have a return value, so `undefined`.